# Pylance: unexpected type inference for a union of two list types

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, pylance

Assume `x` has type `list[int] | list[str]`, that is, it is either a list containing only ints or a list containing only strings.

Then `set(x)` is either a set containing only ints, or a set containing only strings, so I would expect it to have the type `set[int] | set[str]`. However, Pylance infers the type `set[int | str]`, which in my understanding describes a set that may contain *both* ints and strings, so clearly a different type. (Indeed, Pylance then agrees that these two types are not compatible.)

Is this behavior a bug or am I missing something?

#### Example

```
def my_set(x: list[int] | list[str]) -> set[int] | set[str]:
    return set(x)
```

Now Pylance reports at `set(x)`:

```
Expression of type "set[int | str]" cannot be assigned to return type "set[int] | set[str]"
  Type "set[int | str]" cannot be assigned to type "set[int] | set[str]"
    "set[int | str]" is incompatible with "set[int]"
      TypeVar "_T@set" is invariant
        Type "int | str" cannot be assigned to type "int"
          "str" is incompatible with "int"
    "set[int | str]" is incompatible with "set[str]"
      TypeVar "_T@set" is invariant
        Type "int | str" cannot be assigned to type "str"
  ...Pylance(reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a constrained generic type variable: ([PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#generics))

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", str, int)

def my_set(x: list[T]) -> set[T]:
    return set(x)


a = my_set([1, 2, 3])
b = my_set(["x", "y", "z"])

reveal_type(a)  # inferred by `mypy` as `set[int]`
reveal_type(b)  # inferred by `mypy` as `set[str]`
```

I do agree that it is strange that the type is not inferred the way you expected it to. Not sure why that is. Even if there is no way to know, whether `list[int]` or `list[str]` is passed to `set()`, it is certainly either one or the other. So I would also expect the returned type to be inferred as the union of `set[int]` and `set[str]`.

This type inference works with one concrete type:

```py
reveal_type(set([1, 2, 3]))  # inferred as `set[int]`
```

I wonder why it doesn't work with the union.

Interestingly, `mypy` actually completely erases all specificity, as opposed to the wrong `set[int | str]` you got. With `mypy` I get `set[object]`.

Either way, going the generic route is the "more correct" way. That way you will have type certainty for the return value as opposed to a union.

**UPDATE**: I opened an [issue here](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/13960) for `mypy`. In that particular case it seems to stem from the fact that type joins are used. We'll see if/how that will be resolved.